# Looping through & Opening Files based on Range and Period

Tags: vba

I have a project where I need to open all territory files associated with a district in a range of districts, looping through each district.  All files for that district need to be opened in the periods (months) equal to and prior to an inputted month value.  The files need to be opened one at a time with values from certain variant worksheets in that file copied and pasted into another master file.  The structure of the files is Path\Year\District\Period\Territory.xlsx.

I am encountering errors with the following code which attempts to capture the month for the report and compare it to the Period variable.  I am getting the Next without For error.

```
Sub DSMReports()
Sheets("START").Activate
Dim MM As Variant
Dim YYYY As Variant
MM = InputBox("Enter Month for reporting in MM format: 01-12")
YYYY = InputBox("Enter Year for reporting in YYYY format")
Range("C6").Value = MM
Range("C8").Value = YYYY

Dim DistrictDSM As Range
Dim DistrictsDSMList As Range
Set DistrictsDSMList = Start.Range("E11:E23")
Dim Path As String
Dim DistPeriodFile As String
Dim Total As Integer
Dim Period As Integer

For Each DistrictDSM In DistrictsDSMList.Cells
Total = 0
For Period = 1 To MM
Period = Total + 1
If Period < 10 Then Path = "\\corsrv027\Accounting\Monthend " & YYYY & "\DSM Files\" & DistrictDSM & "\P0" & Period
If Period >= 10 Then Path = "\\corsrv027\Accounting\Monthend " & YYYY & "\DSM Files\" & DistrictDSM & "\P" & Period
DistPeriodFile = Dir(Path & "\*.xlsx")
Do While DistPeriodFile <> ""
Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & "\" & DistPeriodFile
'Do copying, pasting, and going through each worksheet one at a time here
DistPeriodFile = Dir
Next Period
Next DistrictDSM
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Move the `Loop` of the `Do While` loop before `Next Period` - your `For` loops should be outside the `Do While` loop.

Comment: Fantastic!  That fixed the problem with the looping!  However, now I'm getting an Run-time error 424: Object required error when I hit the line Set DistrictsDSMList = Start.Range("E11:E23").  Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Never mind.  I didn't need to use Start.Range("E11:E23"), but Range("E11:E23").

Comment: Please, next time use indentations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix the `Next Without For` error by moving the `Loop` of the `Do While` loop *before* the `Next Period` and `Next DistrictDSM`. Indentation visualizes and helps properly structure your loops, and would have highlighted your "interwoven" loop structure.

```
For Each DistrictDSM In DistrictsDSMList.Cells
    ' code
    For Period = 1 To MM
        ' more code
        Do While DistPeriodFile <> ""
            ' more code
        Loop
    Next Period
Next DistrictDSM
```